How to access Prometheus running in a container from localhost
I am following this Prometheus quick start guide to add metrics to a toy service running in a Docker container on my Mac. I have the service defined in a docker-compose.yml. I have added start_http_server(8000) as per the Prometheus guide. There are no errors when I docker-compose up. I can find the container IP, and it is 172.18.0.0/16. However, I cannot access 172.18.0.0/16:8000 from my browser running on the Mac. Do I need to add something to the docker-compose.yml to make this possible? Right now, my docker-compose.yml is very simple:
services:
  my_app:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development

  my_other_app:
    build:
      context: ./my_other_app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - my_app


172.18.0.0/16 is not an address, it is an address range. You need to find the right IP

On a MacOS system, there are at least 4 different "localhosts" in this setup (the two containers, the hidden Linux VM, and the MacOS physical host).  What is trying to make a call to what, from where, with what error?  You never need to look up the Docker-internal IP addresses, and you can't directly access them if you're using Docker Decktop or another similar VM-based setup.

You should put "8000:8000" in ports if you want to access it as well

@DavidMaze I'm just trying to point my browser to "http://localhost:8000/" as per the Prometheus page.

@Matt Actually, that worked!!!
